# Global Variables for data exchange between forms

Tags: vb.net, oop, scope

Is it a good practice using global variables in a VB (.NET) application in order to exchange data between forms?

As global variable I mean a public variable defined in a module and not a public member or property of a class.
Moreover as my personal rule I never access a global variable from a class, but I pass the values to the class via functions.

I know, I am not a friend a global variables and their abuse, but there are some cases in forms data exchange where they seem to be to only way to make simple/clear code.

Example 1: 
my application is started with command line args.
I need to access to this arguments in all my forms: i just read and validate the arguments in my MDI-load event and then store them in  global variables. Thus I can read these values in a very simply way from all my forms.

Example 2:
I'm developing a program that write application's events in a EventLog protocol (like the Windows EventLog).
I wrote the class EventLog that handles adding, showing, saving, sorting the EventLog.
Then I put in a module the global variable **gEventLog** as istance of the class EventLog and created the object when the MDI form is loaded.
In this way I have a global variable and I can handle the EventLog from each forms (MDI and child) in my program.
On the other hand I could have created  EventLog as public member or property of my MDI form and it would have been the same.

I found and read already some discussions, but more tailored on C programming or basic discussion issues, like in:

[Are global variables bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad)

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

and on vb this:

[Declare global variables in Visual Studio 2010 and VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529862/declare-global-varibles-in-vb-2010)

Any suggestions about the particular case of data exchange between forms (and not between classes and other components of the program)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about using an IoC Container?

[Inversion of control (definition from Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)

Comment: Never read about IoC... I've just done for the first time, thank you :-) But IoC would mean designing again all my projects.
IoC is an interesting approach, but I think one must start from scratch...

Comment: A refactoring will of course be needed but this was not your question that ask for any suggestions about the particular case of data exchange between forms. You can also use a ServiceLocator : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx. This way you could encapsulate you command line and logging in a service that your form will be able to consume.