# Splitting a string of characters in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to split a string like the one show below

```
13,14,15,16,17
```

into

`13 14 15 16 17` and store them in an **integer array**

How can I do this?

I need this for my VB.NET project. Just the core concept will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) in this Linq query:

```
Dim intArr = str.Split(","c).Select(Function(s) Int32.Parse(s)).ToArray()
```

or, if you find the query-syntax easier:

```
Dim ints = From str In str.Split(","c)
           Select Int32.Parse(str)
dim intArr = ints.ToArray()
```

here the old approach without Linq but correctly sized array:

```
Dim strArr = str.Split(","c)
Dim intArr(strArr.Length - 1) As Int32
For i As Int32 = 0 To strArr.Length - 1
    intArr(i) = Int32.Parse(strArr(i))
Next
```

Comment: The sting will be entered in a text box control. should i store the text in a variable

Comment: The second code works great. Can you explain how this line of code works?

Comment: The ssecond approach is the same as the first, it's just a different syntax(query instead of method). Have a look: [Introduction to LINQ in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763068.aspx).

Comment: How can I assign the values to a globally declared array?

Comment: @Dineshbabu: In .NET there is no concept of a "globally declared array". So what do you mean?

Comment: @Dineshbabu: In .NET there is no concept of a "globally declared array". So what do you mean?    http://stackoverflow.com/a/4529898/284240

Comment: I need the process of splitting under a condition. If the control comes out of the IF condition the variable is no longer accessible

Comment: @Dineshbabu: Sorry, it's difficult to understand the problem from the comment section. You might want to ask another question for this problem.