# Visual Basic .NET logic

Tags: vb.net

Guys is it possible to declare a variable globally on one form and be able to call that variable on the another form? Or should I say: how do you declare a variable GLOBALLY?

Comment: Google this doubt and there are plenty of examples.

Comment: A good learning starting point [Classes vs Modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881570/classes-vs-modules-in-vb-net), then you could refine your knowldege with some basic search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make the variable `Public`. Better still, make it a public property, e.g.:

```
Private _data As AccountCharacteristics
Public Property Data() As AccountCharacteristics
    Get
        If _data Is Nothing Then
            Data = New AccountCharacteristics()
        End If

        Return _data
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As AccountCharacteristics)
        _data = value

        If value IsNot Nothing Then
            AccountNumber.Text = value.AccountNumber
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

If you want the variable to be shared across all copes of the form, make it `Public Shared` instead

Comment: @Shaw, I thank You man. I think you the one who can help me here... I'm developing ordering system where I add a new customer then "customer form" goes to Order form, it like a process flow... So after adding a new customer going to Order Form, I want that customerID we just added to be shared on the Order Form. I don't know if I make sense... So I'm struggling with putting it down in code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Class` that has a `Shared Property` that you can then access from any `Form` regardless or whether a `Form` has been instantiated or not.

Here is a [Declare global variables in Visual Studio 2010 and VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529862/declare-global-variables-in-visual-studio-2010-and-vb-net) describing what to do.