# How to access public variable accross projects in one solution

Tags: vb.net

I have a publice variable (vrPassword) that is defined in a class.
How to access its data across different projects in a solution?

I do not know if any re fences to this class needs to be given?

Thanks

Comment: If you add a reference to `Project A` in `Project B` and your `vrPassword` is defined `Public Shared` it should be accessible in `Project B`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529862/declare-global-variables-in-visual-studio-2010-and-vb-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve the terminology, if it is defined in a class, then it is either a property or a field, not a variable - variable is always local. I would definitely recommend you using a public property bound to a private field, that's the correct OOP way to do it, so it should look like:

```
Private _vrPassword As String

Public Property vrPassword() As String
    Get
        Return _vrPassword
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _vrPassword = value
    End Set
End Property
```

(Note this is not the best practice of naming conventions, but you weren't asking about it.)

To use it from different project, you need to:

1) Reference the project or .dll file,

2) Add `Imports Namespace.Of.The.Class` to file from where you want to use it (in case the namespace is different)

3) If the variable is not static, you need to instantiate the class:

```
Dim classHoldingTheVariableInstance As New ClassHoldingTheVariable()
Dim password As String = classHoldingTheVariableInstance.vrPassword
```