# Global variables vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, global-variables

I want to make a function in my main form that uses a variable from another function in the form. Also i want to call the first function in another file in the same solution. Is that possible in vb.net?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Please add some code that you have written so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4530099/1070452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just as you called it: With global variables. See the following link for a related question on SO:

- [Declare global variables in Visual Studio 2010 and VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529862/declare-global-variables-in-visual-studio-2010-and-vb-net)

You can call your function from another place in your solution if that method is delared to be `Public` (=visible from outside the class). Take a look here:

- http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets11p3.html